# scipy.optimize.curve_fit con DataFrames de pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, scipy

Estoy trabajando con varios DataaFrames de panda (en este post solo usaré 2 de ellos por simplicidad). Me gustaría llevar a cabo un ajuste de ambos de ellos usando `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`.

La idea es: utilizar las columnas de un dataframe (mencionado en el codigo como *new_freqs*) como variable independiente-x; y las columnas del otro dataframe (nombrado como *Tans*) como variable dependiente-y. Ambos dataframes tienen dimension de (12,6) donde la primera columna de *new_freqs* se corresponde con la primera columna de *Tans*, de tal forma que forman el conjunto de puntos (x,y).

A continuacion incluyo la parte del codigo más relevante:

```
In[1]:
print(type(Tans), Tans.shape)
print(type(new_freqs), new_freqs.shape)
Out[1]:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> (12, 6)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> (12, 6)
```

Estoy intentando realizar un ajuste lineal:

```
def linear(frequencies,tau):
    return 2*np.pi*new_freqs*tau

popt, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(linear, new_freqs, Tans, p0=None, maxfev=1000)
tau = popt
fit = lambda frequencies: 2*np.pi*new_freqs*tau
fitted = linear(new_freqs,tau)
print(popt, pcov)
```

Quisiera conseguir una linea recta del ajusto para pintarla junto los pares de valores (x,y) y obtener un array con los valores del ajuste *tau* para cada set de columnas (x,y).

Cada vez que ejecuto el código obtengo este error:

```
ValueError: object too deep for desired array

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\XXXXXXXXX.py", line 210, in <module>
    popt, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(linear, new_freqs, Tans, p0=None, maxfev=1000)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 763, in curve_fit
    res = leastsq(func, p0, Dfun=jac, full_output=1, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 401, in leastsq
    gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
minpack.error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats.
```

Alguna idea/consejo de porque ocurre esto, o como puedo solventar este problema?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

he resulto la duda utilizando una iteración sobre columnas.
El siguiente código muestra un ejemplo por si a alguien le puede servir.

```
def linear(new_freqs, tau):
    return 2.0*np.pi*new_freqs*tau

def fit_linear(new_freqs, Tan):
    Taus_lin = []
    Fit_tang_lin = []
    count = 0
    for count in range(len(cols_names)):
        popt, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(linear, new_freqs.iloc[:,count], Tan.iloc[:,count], p0=None, maxfev=5000)
        tau = popt
        fitted_Tan = linear(new_freqs.iloc[:,count],tau)
        Taus_lin.append(tau)
        Fit_tang_lin.append(fitted_Tan)
    Taus_lin = pd.DataFrame(np.transpose(Taus_lin), columns=cols_names)
    Fit_tang_lin = pd.DataFrame(np.transpose(Fit_tang_lin), columns=cols_names)
    return Taus_lin, Fit_tang_lin
```